# Illegal Invocation in AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am building a web-app in JQuery that needs to communicate with a server.
I have used this exact same code several times, the only thing that's changed is the data and the code performed on success.

For some reason, whenever I run this function I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`. I have no idea what this error means, nor how to fix it.

```
function addCourse(course){
console.log("Starting add course");
var data = {
  "fn" : "cAdd",
  "name": course,
  "ajax" : "true"
};
console.log("Starting AJAX call");
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: SERVICE_URL,
  data: data,
  contentType: "application/json",
  success: function(response) {
      console.log("Success!");
    console.log(response);
    alert("the course "+ course + "has been added");
    loadAllCourses();
    }
});
console.log("end of mod retrieval")
}
```

the function is bound to a button, using this code, from inside the `$(document).ready() function`

```
$(document).on("click", "#saveNCourse", function(event){
    var name = $("#ncName");
    addCourse(name);
});
```

If somebody could briefly explain what an Illegal Invocation is and/or show me where I have gone wrong in this code I would really appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you specifing `contentType: "application/json",` when you are making a GET request? There is no content in the request body to describe the type of.

Comment: "I get the error" — Does your debugger tell you what line of code threw that error?

Comment: Where are you invoking (calling) the function?

Comment: You have a bunch of `console.log` and `alert` statements. Which ones run successfully?

Comment: the console says `jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4` threw the error --- the last log to run successfully is "Starting AJAX call"

Comment: the function is bound to a button on the HTML document -- i will add the bind to the question

Comment: @JamieMcAllister have you tried adding proper `dataType`?

Comment: Can't debug as easily using min file. Use development version to see where error is being caught by examining the actual code, then look where that occurs in your code

Comment: `course` BTW what is it?

Comment: @ Jamie McAllister you need to `data:json.stringify(data)`

Comment: what would be the proper `dataType` @Jai ? @charlietfl it never occured to me that the min version wasn't good for developing

Comment: What's in `course` that you're adding to data?

Comment: `course` is a string

Comment: @Ozil that's not true. Passing object is most common. $.ajax will urlencode that object for a get request

Comment: `course` is apparently not a string :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this is causing the issue:

```
var name = $("#ncName"); // you have to get the value/text of it
addCourse(name);
```

so you can change it to:

```
var name = $("#ncName").val(); // $("#ncName").text(); in case if it is not a form control.
addCourse(name);
```

Comment: see those moments when you realize you spent an hr trying to fix a problem in the wrong function? -_- thanks, i can't believe i forgot to put `.val()` at the end of that line.